# What is wrong with my CS50 mario less comfortable code?

Tags: c, cs50

Here is a copy of my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = get_int("Please enter a height between 1 and 8 (inclusive)\nHeight: ");

    if(0 < height && height < 9)
    for(int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
    {
        for(int s = (height - 1); s >= 1; s--)
        {
            printf("a");
        }

        for(int h = 1; h <= i; h++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    else
    printf("Please try again.\n"),
    main();
}
```

The part I cannot seem to get right is printing the correct number of spaces as it does not seem to reduce the variable "s" after each loop. (I have replaced the spaces with the letter "a" so I can see where the code has gone wrong.)
The aim of the code is to print a pyramid of #'s that is right-aligned.
Where have I gone wrong here?

So for example, if the user inputs a height of 3, the output will be:

```
aa

aa#

aa##

aa###
```

however, I would like the output to be:

```
aa#

a##

###
```

Comment: What is the code doing wrong, exactly?  Printing the wrong number of spaces?  Perhaps you could show us the output and explain why it's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**The main issue** is the 2nd for loop in your code when you print "a". Everytime you hit in this particular loop, you basically print (height - 1) times "a". In fact, you should print every time one less "a" (and one more hashes). To achieve this, we need to tweak condition of s.
Instead of this

`int s = height - 1; s >= 1`

Use this

`int s = height - i; s > 1`

Since your main loop has iterator `i`, we can use it here.

**Second issue** is that according to CS50 problem set description, you should actually print `" "` (spaces), not `"a"`. For this, you should replace `"a"` with `" "`.

**Third issue** is your code prints an extra line with full of space in the begining. You need to tweak the main for loop with this condition to remove one extra line.

```
i < height
```

And in the for loop where you print `#` symbol, you need to start iterator h from zero, so that it prints right away with the first line.

```
int h = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use the built-in functionality of `printf` that is already in place, reducing the problem to a single, simple loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = get_int("Please enter a height between 1 and 8 (inclusive)\nHeight: ");

    unsigned char blocks[height];
    memset(blocks, '#', height);

    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", height, i+1, blocks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4212KB
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```